# How to change color scheme of an intranet template running SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, 2007, master-page

We're in the process of phasing out SP2007 to a new solution however since this will take 6 months+ our CEO wants to freshen up the look/feel of the current SP2007 intranet page. I have uploaded an image of what it currently looks like and this is what I want to propose;

1. change color of the side panels from black to white
2. Change the intranet square background from light grey to white
3. Change the ascents from green to blue.

I am slightly comfortable cutting code and have SP 2007 designer installed on my laptop but really hoping I just need to update some color codes then be done.

I want to know if this is possible and where/how to find the correct file to copy > edit > apply to production.

Hopefully, someone out there still remembers SP2007!

[image: Current SP2007 Intranet template]